# Groovy to use variables as template

Tags: string, templates, groovy

In Groovy, is it possible to define variables as template first then use them later?

Like predefine `body` before knowing the content of `subject`:

```
body = 'Hello, ${subject}!'
subject = "World"
```

Then get `Hello, World!` from the `body` template (after the content of `subject` is defined) somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a closure inside a `GString`, so instead of capturing the value on creation of the `GString`, it gets evaluated when it has to manifest into a string.

```
body = "Hello, ${-> subject}!"
subject = "World"

println body
// → Hello, World!
```

Comment: Perfect! Accepting this as it is the kind of _simple_ answer I was hoping for. For the _formal_ TemplateEngine solution, please refer to daggett's answer.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html

```
def body = 'Hello, ${subject.toUpperCase()}!'

def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(body) // heavy operation - better to cache it

def binding = [
    subject: 'world'
]

println template.make(binding).toString()

println template.make(subject: 'john').toString()
```

output:

```
Hello, WORLD!
Hello, JOHN!
```

---

more examples here:

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html

Comment: Yeah, I asked this question after seeing this approach, which is in my view, although very formal, but a bit over-complicated, if compare to Perl or Python. Upvote for this standard approach1

Comment: not sure what you are looking then. there is an option to use string format: `String.format('Hello %s!', subject)`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a feature in `Groovy`, but usually it is not that difficult to solve the problem by using `String.replaceAll` method:

```
def bodyTemplate = 'Hello, ${subject}!'
def subject = "World"
def body = bodyTemplate.replaceAll('\\$\\{subject}', subject)
println "body = $body"
```